# JavaFX: Pass arguments from JavaScript to JNLP

Tags: java, javascript, jnlp, argument-passing

I am trying to deploy JavaFX 2 app using Java Web start (generated by NetBeans) and I need to pass some args to my app using JavaScript.

First question: Is it even possible?
Second question: If it is possible, how can I do it. :-)

My JNLP file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" href="MD.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>MD</title>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <resources>
    <jfx:javafx-runtime version="2.2+" href="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/GetFile/javafx-latest/windows-i586/javafx2.jnlp"/>
  </resources>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="MD.jar" size="675286" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar" size="519899" download="eager" />
  </resources>
<security>
  <all-permissions/>
</security>

  <applet-desc  width="800" height="600" main-class="com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback"  name="MD" >
    <param name="requiredFXVersion" value="2.2+"/>
  </applet-desc>
  <jfx:javafx-desc  width="800" height="600" main-class="com.blabla.MD"  name="MD" >
    <fx:param name="jmeno" value="hodnota"/>
  </jfx:javafx-desc>
  <update check="always"/>
</jnlp>
```

And my web page has this code:

```
<SCRIPT src="./web-files/dtjava.js"></SCRIPT>
<script>
function launchApplication(jnlpfile) {
    dtjava.launch(            {
            url : 'MD.jnlp',
        },
        {
            javafx : '2.2+'
        },
        {}
    );
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Thx. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED:

```
function launchApplication(jnlpfile) {
            dtjava.launch({
                url: 'MD.jnlp',
                params: {'name':'value'}
            },
            {
                javafx: '2.2+'
            },
            {}
            );
            return false;
        }
```

and in JavaFX app, parameters are not in String[] args, but you have to get with method:

```
getParameters();
```

This is documented in the [JavaFX Deployment Guide documentation for the Java Deployment Tookit (dtjava.js)](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/deployment_toolkit.htm#BABDJDEC) as well as the JavaFX Application [getParameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.html#getParameters%28%29) method JavaDoc.

Comment: Is it possible to pass Array as parameter instead of String?

Answer (score 1):

> First question: Is it even possible?

Yes, in general it is possible. I have done something similar but not directly from JavaScript to JNLP.

> Second question: If it is possible, how can I do it. :-)

In my scenario I have done only JNLP part and not JS. But think this way: user logins at web page via one of social networks (JS is involved). JS and Ajax passes required values to server side and redirect user to a page where JNLP applet is deployed.

At server side there is a jnlp file template:

```
<fx:param name="jmeno" value="{value}"/>
```

then since server got a value via Ajax it can generate proper jnlp file using PHP or JSP and give it to a user's browser.